# how to compare two images based on luminosity of each pixel on matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, comparison, pixel, luminance

I am working on a project in which I have to compare two b&w images based on their luminosity. I wanted to create a program that compares the pixels of each image using MATLAB and I wanted some advice on how I could do this.

Comment: If these images have three colour channels (RGB image but appears black and white) you can use the [rgb2lab()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rgb2lab.html) function. Then take the first channel which will correspond to the luminance.

Comment: Some methods of comparing can include logical comparisons or histograms.

Comment: Could you share links to two representative images so that we understand this better? I can think of several metrics - Sum of Square Differences (SSD), Sum of Absolute Differences (SAD) and so on.